# jquery overlapping gallery, z-index issue

Tags: jquery, css

Here's a fiddle of what i've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/z4vaB/

My problem is that i can't make images properly go under each other after the image is hovered.   I need every other image apart from the hovered one to snap under each other, right now they just stay how the first `for` loop has them assigned. I imagine I should somehow assign new `z-index` values, but I can't figure out a proper pattern.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having problems understanding what the problem is. The demo seems to work in that hovering one image brings it to the front and then on mouse out the image moves back to it's original layer. Could you please expand on your description of the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z4vaB/1/ Is this the one you are looking for?

Comment: @andyb I need the pictures to arrange before the hovered picture so that they are under each other, like they are currently arranged to the right. I hover on the picture, and every other picture before it should arrange under each other. My english sucks though, can't help it.